# Optimize integration region

Tags: optimization

I have an optimization problem: I have a 2-D square like 0<x<X and 0<y<Y where X and Y are the boundaries of the square, and I have a 2-D array in this region Arr[x,y], which has positive and negative values.

Now, the task is to find the optimal region inside this square so that when I integrate the given array within this region, I get the maximum possible number.

Which direction should I look? Which techniques are available for this type of question?

Comment: I think you are looking for the **max-sum-rectangle problem**. There exist clever algorithms for this, but it can also be solved by formulating a Mixed-Integer Programming model. Both approaches are very interesting.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do not "announce" your questions, don't add "thanks" etc, and do not spam irrelevant tags (edited).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.